# How Do You Use CustomView From The Design Palette In Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I click on `CustomView` a list of views from support libraries is shown. I can click any and press 'ok' but nothing happens. Is this just a reference for you to manually type them into the xml or is there a way to drag these in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These controls must be manually added via XML. Since they are part of support libraries, they do not come installed into the Android Studio Editor and they have to be added manually in the layout XML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to drag the `CustomView` (or, in more recent versions, `<view>`) entry from the palette to your design.  This will then give you a list.  When you select the item from the list, it will be added to your design at the place you dropped it.